# PerformanceNavigationTiming returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, performance, web-extension

I am using the PerformanceObserver API in a web extension to get the PerformanceNavigationTiming.

`this.performanceObserver.observe({ type: "navigation", buffered: true })`

I have several users that installed my extensions and globally I have good value. However, I saw that from time to time I receive wrong values. Here an example:

```
{
  "name": "anonymized",
  "entryType": "navigation",
  "startTime": 0,
  "duration": 1618111,
  "initiatorType": "navigation",
  "nextHopProtocol": "http/1.1",
  "workerStart": 0,
  "redirectStart": 1617474,
  "redirectEnd": 1617474,
  "fetchStart": 1617474,
  "domainLookupStart": 1617474,
  "domainLookupEnd": 1617474,
  "connectStart": 1617474,
  "connectEnd": 1617474,
  "secureConnectionStart": 1617474,
  "requestStart": 1617481,
  "responseStart": 1617573,
  "responseEnd": 1617573,
  "transferSize": 8380,
  "encodedBodySize": 7609,
  "decodedBodySize": 37651,
  "serverTiming": [],
  "unloadEventStart": 1617578,
  "unloadEventEnd": 1617578,
  "domInteractive": 32,
  "domContentLoadedEventStart": 91,
  "domContentLoadedEventEnd": 93,
  "domComplete": 1618094,
  "loadEventStart": 1618094,
  "loadEventEnd": 1618111,
  "type": "reload",
  "redirectCount": 0
}
```

There are 2 facts that make me doubt about the validity of this PerformanceNavigationTiming:

1. The duration reported is over 25 minutes, and this is unlikely
2. Checking the [MDN PerformanceNavigationTiming page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming), it shows that the domContentLoadedEventStart and domContentLoadedEventEnd are happening in the processing block, almost at the end of the navigation cycle. However, here we have a really low values, respectively 91 and 93.

Do you know if I am missing something? Or maybe is there a bug on the API?

Thanks